# Convert specific columns from float to Decimal

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where I need to convert specific column ranges from floats to decimals (and have them all go out 5 decimal places). 
I am having a difficult time converting the columns. 
Can someone help me do so, preferably using `iloc`? 
I have a sample code below that illustrates what I am looking for (there is code to generate sample data). I receive the following error when I run this.

**Traceback:**

> "TypeError: ('conversion from Series to Decimal is not supported',
>   'occurred at index B')"

```
import pandas as pd 
from pandas import util
import numpy as np
from decimal import Decimal

df= util.testing.makeDataFrame()
df.head()       
df.iloc[:, 1:4].apply(Decimal)
```

Comment: What goes wrong with your approach?

Comment: Good point, I'll update the question with the error I receive.

Comment: Dhimmel90 can you also provide some sample data that is similar to what your df looks like?

Comment: @DavidErickson the sample code I included generates sample data (df=util.testing.makeDataFrame())

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`apply` on a Dataframe applies a function to all the columns of that dataframe which are `Series`. You have to go one step further and apply `Decimal` to the individual cells of each `Series`:

```
df.iloc[:, 1:4] = df.iloc[:, 1:4].apply(lambda x: x.apply(Decimal))
```

If you want to `quantize` the Decimal, just use another `lambda`:

```
df.iloc[:, 1:4] = df.iloc[:, 1:4].apply(lambda x: x.apply(
    lambda y: Decimal(y).quantize(Decimal('1.00000'))))
```

Comment: This is SUPER close to what I need. How can I include a quantize statement in there that rounds all decimals to the 5th spot (per original question)?

Comment: I had to make a small modification to Serge solution `df.iloc[:, 1:4] = df.iloc[:, 1:4].apply(lambda x: Decimal(x))`

Answer (score 0):

@Serge Ballesta If you use round instead of decimal, then that would round it appropriately; however, as you may know that then converts it to a float. If your goal is to keep the column as a "Decimal", which in Pandas is an "Object" rather than a float, then, you could add .astype(str) to the end after rounding to the desired amount of digits.

```
import pandas as pd 
from pandas import util
import numpy as np
from decimal import Decimal

df = util.testing.makeDataFrame()    
df.iloc[:, 1:4] = df.iloc[:, 1:4].round(5).astype(str)
df
```